# Autocomplete TextBox Column in DataGridView Stopped working

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview with one of its column as TextBox. I wrote a function to populate values from database and suggest values to autocomplete the text. I achieved it, and then I started coding to make a column auto increment (Sr.No) , so I wrote some more lines of code and changed some properties and  all of a sudden the textbox stopped auto-completing. Now I tried every possible step to make it work but failed. I dont know what is the property that I changed affected this. 
I am putting my code here, please help

This is the code for Editingcontrolshowing event...

```
 Private Sub DataGridView2_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.EditingControlShowing


    DataGridView2.BeginEdit(True)
    Dim autoText As TextBox = TryCast(e.Control, TextBox)
    If autoText IsNot Nothing Then
        autoText.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        autoText.AutoCompleteCustomSource = AutoCompleteLoad()
        autoText.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the autocomplete function where I loaded values...

```
 Public Function AutoCompleteLoad() As AutoCompleteStringCollection
    Dim str As AutoCompleteStringCollection = New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
    Dim ConnectionString As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("data source=ADMIN-PC\SQLEXPRESS; database=billdev;Trusted_Connection=yes;")
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * from bill;"
    Dim SQLcommand As New SqlCommand(strSQL, ConnectionString)
    ConnectionString.Open()
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader
    reader = SQLcommand.ExecuteReader()

    While reader.Read()
        str.Add(reader.Item(1))
    End While

    Return str

End Function
```

This is the extra code I added before it stopped working, but I think this doesn't make any difference

```
    Private Sub DataGridView2_RowPrePaint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.RowPrePaint

    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Me.DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = e.RowIndex + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code, i.e. set breakpoints and stepped through it, examining the state as you go?  Exactly where and how does it behave differently to your expectations?

Comment: Also, why are you doing a `SELECT *` in your query if you only want one column?  Project only the column you actually want to use.

Comment: Yes, actually I got the solution. I put on the wrap property of the column. And Yes I want some more columns to get populated in the data grid view. So, I did SELECT * query.

Comment: That you want other grid columns populated is irrelevant to your autocomplete. Look at your `AutoCompleteLoad` method. Your query projects all columns but then you only use one. There's no point retrieving data that you don;t use, so don;t retrieve it.  Also, you're not closing your data reader ort your connection, which is bad. They should both be created with `Using` statements so they will be closed implicitly.

Comment: I didn't post the complete code here, it was just for your reference. Even the column names are different in the example mentioned above in the question. Still, I got a help from you about the `USING` statement property of closing connections implicitly. THANK YOU!

Comment: *"I didn't post the complete code here"*. OK, that casts things in a different light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I tried changing every property of the datagridview randomly. And finally got to the point.
It is the `WRAP` property of the column itself.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I had the problem of the autocomplete not working, and yes the Word Wrap stopped the autocomplete from working. Thanks Shreekant, sorry it took you ages to find out, but it sure helped me.

Also to do it for just one column, in the EditingControlShowing procedure, I used:

If the_DataGridView.Columns(the_DataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText = "the header text"

So that it only applies to that column. So many web pages and YouTube videos check for column(1) which is pure nonsense.